# What happens if I delete an S3 object before replication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Long time listener, first time caller...

If I have an S3 bucket which is versioned (as per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html) for replication) and bucket replication is enabled; what happens if the source bucket object is deleted **before** replication has taken place?

I'm assuming (as the source bucket is versioned) the replication will still take place. The replication logic surely sees a new object creation event and replicates this in the destination bucket. Because I've not specified any other configuration, the delete marker subsequently placed on the source bucket object will not be replicated onto the destination object. Therefore it should just appear as normal in the destination bucket and not be visible in the source bucket.

I can't find anything concrete in the documentation that clarifies the position on this situation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which option you choose in your replication configuration:

- V1: the delete marker is replicated - a subsequent GET request to the deleted object does not return the object in either the source or the destination bucket.
- V2: the delete marker is **not** replicated - a subsequent GET request to the deleted object returns the object only in the destination bucket.

For more, see [Managing delete marker replication in Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/managing-delete-marker-replication-in-amazon-s3/).

Comment: I did see this, but I'm not sure it entirely clarifies the point being made. To rephrase my original question slightly will my file get replicated if it's 'deleted' before replication has taken place. A scenario: Suppose bucket A is replicated to bucket B with V2 (default configuration)

1. Upload file x to bucket A

2. Immediately delete x from bucket A (before replication to B supposing x is large)

Will file x still turn up in bucket B?

Comment: Both source and destination buckets must have versioning enabled. If you delete object x from bucket A then that simply writes a delete marker to bucket A. With V2, the object versions prior to the delete marker would be replicated to bucket B, no?

Comment: That's my assumption, perhaps the documentation does cover this and I'm misinterpreting it but that is certainly my expectation.

Comment: The documentation, any documentation, is unlikely to answer every detailed question you might have. You could try this scenario to see what happens. I'd be surprised if object x was not replicated to bucket B, as it wouldn't match the general description of how the feature behaves.